# Cols inside Cols bootstrap padding right left issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

```
    <div class="first-row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="row first-row">
                 <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <label>Test Type</label>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <select class="form-control">
                       <option value="-1">Please select</option>
                       <option value="2">Operating System</option>
                       <option value="3">U</option>
                     </select>
                 </div>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Is this valid in bootstrap
1.  row inside row
2.  mulitple cols inside cols

I know both will run but is this the right method and when we do col inside col we have to face issue with the padding of the upper col div as well as the inner div ....so i have to manually make padding right 0px.I just want to know whether is this the right way...or any other approach pls suggest

Comment: A row is provided for 12 cols in bootstrap, so do you have another <div class="col-sm-6"> inside your first row? Aside from that, yes, you can work with rows inside columns, but unless you have multiple rows to put inside, I'm not sure why you would want to. You will indeed have to take care of the padding.

Answer (score 1):

In Bootstrap generally you have to use `.row` to wrap your cols because `.row` has two main roles :

1. cols have `float:left` property which mean the height of the container of your cols will shrink and damage the flow of the page so `.row` fix it by adding

   ```
   .row:after{
    display:table;
    content:'';
    clear:both;
   }
   ```
2. `.row` clear the unwanted padding of the most left col and the most right col by adding negative margins

   ```
   .row{
    margin-left:-15px;
    margin-right:-15px;
   }
   ```

   so if you have nested cols you have to wrap it in a row like

   ```
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-6">
       <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-sm-3">

            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-9">

            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
   </div>
   ```